# Can't stop a timer

Tags: c#, .net, timer, progress-bar

I can't stop this timer :

```
    private void startTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void AppTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BarreProgression.Value < BarreProgression.Maximum)
        {
            ...
            BarreProgression.Value = BarreProgression.Value + 1;
        }
        else if (BarreProgression.Value == BarreProgression.Maximum)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Finished");
            //AppTimer.Stop();
            AppTimer.Enabled = false;  
        }
    }
```

I have an infinity number of message boxes!
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see the `Finished` dialog?

Comment: First Stop the Timer, Then irritate the user with the Popup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A MessageBox blocks the execution until the user closes it so first stop the timer then show the message or you will get spammed by windows:

```
AppTimer.Enabled = false;  
MessageBox.Show("Finished");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to move your Timer stop, one line higher:

```
        else if (BarreProgression.Value == BarreProgression.Maximum)
    {

        // This should be above the message box.
        AppTimer.Enabled = false;  
        MessageBox.Show("Finished");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 if (BarreProgression.Value < BarreProgression.Maximum)
        {
            ...
            BarreProgression.Value = BarreProgression.Value + 1;
        }
        else if (BarreProgression.Value == BarreProgression.Maximum)
        {

            //AppTimer.Stop();
            AppTimer.Enabled = false;  
            MessageBox.Show("Finished");
        }
```